# Smallest $\mathbb R$-algebra which contains a subgroup isomorphic to $A_4$

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

$A_4$ (the alternating group on $4$ elements) can be thought of as the group of direct Euclidean isometries of a regular tetrahedron. This shows that there is a subgroup of the algebra of $3\times3$ matrices which contains it. This algebra is $9$ dimensional. There is no subgroup of the quaternion algebra $\mathbb H$ which is isomorphic to $A_4$, because there is only one element in $\mathbb H$ which has order exactly $2$, and that is $-1$, and there are three elements of $A_4$ of order $2$. It's possible that a subgroup of the $2 \times 2$ real matrices could work, but it looks like a lot of work to show that, if it is indeed the case.

What is the smallest associative and unital algebra over $\mathbb R$ which contains a subgroup isomorphic to $A_4$?

Comment: I'd guess it's (for any finite group, any field) the same as the same question with "semisimple algebra". In the complex case, it would follow the answer is given by minimizing, over all faithful reps with irreducible decomposition $\sum n_i$, the number $\sum n_i^2$. I'm not 100% sure about details, but I guess one can't improve dimension 9 for $\mathrm{Alt}_4$.

Answer (score 6):

Any $k$-algebra $A$ with a subgroup isomorphic to $G$ gives you an algebra homomorphism $kG \to A$. Since you are looking for the smallest algebra, you immediately get surjectivity, i.e. $A$ is a quotient of $kG$. Since you're in characteristic zero, $kG$ is a direct product of matrix algebras so that $A$ itself must be a product of matrix algebras. In particular, that would give you a representation of $G$ over $k$ that is faithful by assumption. And conversely, any faithful representation gives you an algebra homomorphism from $kG$ into a product of matrix rings that is injective on $G$.

A look at the character table of $A_4$ shows that there is a (unique) faithful 3-dimensional representation over $\mathbb{C}$, but no smaller one. In particular, there are also no faithful representations over $\mathbb{R}$ of dimension $<3$. The representation in question is the one coming from the permutation representation, so that it is indeed already defined over $\mathbb{R}$.

In other words: Dimension $9$ is the best you can do.

Answer (score 4):

It is a consequence of Clifford's theorem that it is not possible to embed $A_{4}$ in such a real algebra of dimension less than $9$. There must be an involution of $A_{4}$ acting non-trivially in the associated representation. Then since all involutions of $A_{4}$ are conjugate, every involution in $A_{4}$ must act non-trivially. Let $V$ be the normal Sylow $2$-subgroup of $A_{4}$. Then the three non-trivial $1$-dimensional representations of $V$ are permuted transitively by $A_{4}.$
Thus $A_{4}$ acts (absolutely) irreducibly on a $3$-dimensional submodule of the underlying module, and its elements span the endomorphism algebra of this submodule, which is $9$-dimensional.